# Concrete5: When and how do I use the duplicate() function in the block controller?

Tags: concrete5

I am finding it hard to understand the concept of duplicate() function of the controller.

In the C5 documentation, it says:

`Run automatically when a block is duplicated. This most likely happens when a block that is in an approved version is updated...`

When a block in an approved version is updated, isn't that just saved, as handled by the save() function?

I am also not sure what goes inside this function. Can someone please clarify?

Also does duplicate() function handle situation when a block is pasted from the clipboard?

Answer (score 4):

Before the block is saved, it needs to be duplicated, so that the saving is done to a new version. (Then that new version is associated with the new page version that's created.)

If you look at https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5/blob/master/web/concrete/core/libraries/block_controller.php#L197 you'll see that the base class has a pretty simple duplicate method. If your block is simple (mostly insofar as it having a single DB table), then this should work fine and you don't have to overload it.

The slideshow block has an example of a situation in which you need to overload duplicate(). Not only does it have the "normal" table, but also a linked table of image IDs. So it first calls the parent method, which duplicates the normal block table, and then does its own duplicating.

Go ahead and edit / paste a few Content blocks while watching the `Blocks` table and you'll see when new blocks get created. Remember to publish in between edits.

You'll notice that when new ones *are* created, they get a new `bID` (which makes sense). Now take a look at `btContentLocal`. You'll notice that there's a new entry for each new block ID (matching the `bID`s from `Blocks`). That's what `duplicate()` does -- it creates a new row every time the block is edited. Everything works fine, and it works automatically.

But if you have some rows in a `MyBlock'sSecondaryTable`, then I guarantee you those rows won't get created / copied with the new `bID`. Thus, if your block relies on the secondary table having a `bID` to link to the instance of the block, then the new (updated) block will have a new `bID` and not be able to "find" the old records.

That's what slideshow does. You have `bID` == 1. There are a bunch of `btSlideshowImg` rows with `bID` 1, and one row for each file. When you edit the slideshow block, you get `bID` == 2. The existing `btSlideshowImg` rows don't get updated with the new `bID` -- they're retained so that you can revert the version. (This is why reverting works fine... it's not the reverting that `duplicate()` handles, but the new version.)

(Duplicate() is not called immediately after pasting a block from the scrapbook (clipboard). It appears to be much like creating a new page of a particular page type -- the block is initially created as an alias and only when you first edit it does it duplicate -- but duplicate() does get called.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am still struggling to grasp the concept of duplicate() function. In my block I am using 2 tables. My save() function handles saving to the secondary table and also calls the parent save() method. I made several changes to my block and managed to successfully revert back to the previous versions of the page with older block data. Everything seems to work perfectly for me WITHOUT the duplicate() function...

Comment: ...I had a look at C5's slideshow block. When I copy and paste it from the clipboard, the slideshow block does not seem to create a new id in the database instantly. Only when I edit the new block and save again, it creates a new id for it. This is the exact same behaviour with my own block as well. So it looks like duplicate() function is not doing anything for pasting from the clipboard? I'm still not sure when I should be using duplicate() or is it purely optional in my case?

Comment: duplicate() *is* getting called on paste -- but only after save. Add `Log::addEntry("block duplicated $newBID");` as the first line of the `duplicate()` method in `Concrete5_Library_BlockController` for testing and watch what happens and when. The new ID will always happen without problems -- it's what happens in "secondary" tables (or anything else that links to the bID) that duplicate() is responsible for. .... Hope the edits to my answer helped. Without your code examples and other specifics, there's not much else I can say.

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate function is called whenever assigning templates or copying/pasting blocks.

The duplicate function is necessary mostly with add-ons that need to save in more than one table.

Add-ons can only be aware of one table and will only manage that one table automatically.

The slideshow add-on for instance will save settings in one table and a list of images in another table. The data will be linked through the bID field.

When you edit your block, the save function deals with the two tables. However, when assigning a template or pasting a block (for instance) the bID of the block will change without you editing so it will not go through the save function.

Without the duplicate function, what would happen is that the new bID would be saved in the main table but it would not be saved in the secondary table which means the slideshow would not show any image.

Remember, add-ons are only aware of the main table, any other table has to be dealt woth manually.